# SQL one to one mapping with select query only

Tags: sql, database, select, cursor

I have two table with name LeftTable and RightTable as below

**LeftTable**

```
obsid    Name      Value                 
1        Ronak     A                      
2        Aakash    B                      
3        Pankti    C                      
4        Sanket    D
```

**RightTable**

```
obsid        Name       Value
1            Jhone      F
2            Isabella   M
3            Jonathan   L
4            javafx     p
```

Now when I Left join in some condition the output will be as below

**ResultTable**

```
obsid    Name      Value                  obsid        Name       Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        Ronak     A                      1            Jhone      F
1        Ronak     A                      2            Isabella   M
1        Ronak     A                      3            Jonathan   L
1        Ronak     A                      4            javafx     p
2        Aakash    B                      2            Isabella   M
2        Aakash    B                      3            Jonathan   L 
2        Aakash    B                      4            javafx     p
3        Pankti    C                      3            Jonathan   L
3        Pankti    C                      4            javafx     p
4        Sanket    D                      4            javafx     p
```

This Left Join is help me to achieve One-To-Many Relationship in my application.

Left join condition is dynamic in my application. so its just an example I shown here. Suppose Left Join condition in above exampple is LeftTable.Obsid <= RightTable.Obsid
Now I want to achieve One-To-One relationship.
One-To-One relationship means when any of righttable record linked once with any lefttable record then  that righttble record can not be linked with any other lefttable record.

For above example Output for one to one is as below

```
obsid    Name      Value                  obsid        Name       Value
1        Ronak     A                      1            Jhone      F
2        Aakash    B                      2            Isabella   M
3        Pankti    C                      3            Jonathan   L
4        Sanket    D                      4            javafx     p
```

I have achieve this functionality two way:

1. Using cursor
2. fetching one by one record using select query

Database tables are dynamic in my application. so while processing on millions of record takes too much time as fetching one by one record and processing on it takes time.

Is there any way to achieve One-To-One relation in single select query??

I want to avoid fetching one by one record and I am using Mysql database

Please help me.

Comment: please provide proper data and structure on this http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: show your query what have you done!

Comment: Can you clarify the join you currently have and the relationship between the 2 tables?

Comment: `JOIN .... ON LeftTable.obsid=rightTable.obsid`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM LeftTable AS l INNER JOIN RightTable AS r ON r.obsid= l.obsid`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the required output which is shown in the example by just using inner join.

```
select * from LeftTable L inner join RightTable R
on L.obsid=R.obsid
```

But I if there are duplicate obsid in the left table you can use the below query

```
   select  A.obsid,A.Name,A.Value, R.obsid,R.Name,R.Value from(
     select *,row_number() over (partition by obsid order by obsid ) as row_num 
    from LeftTable)A
     inner join RightTable R
     on A.obsid=R.obsid
     where A.row_num=1
```

Please let me know this is what you expect

Comment: Hi Joe thnx for replay but I am using MySQL database so can you please suggest your query in MySql?

Comment: @user1479110: The first query with the (inner) JOIN does the job.  What was the condition in your LEFT JOIN?  `ON l.obsid <= r.obsid`?  If so, your sample output is missing a line.

Comment: yes you are right Jonathan.. I have updated my question now please help me